# Print NSError in try catch block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, try-catch, nserror

I was curious if anyone knew how to use a try catch in objective c in order to print out a possible NSError received from a synchronousRequest.

The error that I am receiving is due to a non valid memory address. my try catch looks like

```
@try{
    NSLog(@"%@", err);
 }@catch(NSException *e){
    NSLog(@"No error thrown");
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [error handling with NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069039/error-handling-with-nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@catch` block should contain the code that you want to run if there *is* an error.

```
@try {
  // Do the request
  NSLog(@"No error thrown");
} @catch (NSException *e) {
  NSLog(@"%@", err);
}
```

Comment: err is an NSError object. I wanted to print it out in general, but if it did not get set by the synchrousRequest then it was empty. It was because I was being dumb and not initializing it. I was hoping that you could catch a non initialized error? I don't know why but I thought it would save memory somewhere down the line.