# iPhone: How to handle network response exceptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking, nsurlconnection

In Objective-C, how should we handle networking exceptions?

In this case, the server is returning JSON with the wrong keys. So, when I try to fetch a user in Core Data, I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
    reason: 'Invalid predicate: nil RHS'
```

What's the best way to handle this exception?

Comment: You need to check for nil keys and verify the data returned before creating your predicate.

Comment: try-catch block could be a solution..

Comment: That's not a networking-related exception, that's an exception because you aren't validating external data that you've acquired. You should be checking that anything you retrieve externally is as you expect it before use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused with your question, but I hope this helps... here are two questions that refer to a similar subject, checking the answers out on these may help you out:

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069039/error-handling-with-nsurlconnection-sendsynchronousrequest) <-- Read the second answer first, the one with 25 votes really covers some stuff that might help you out.

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808929/handling-nserror-when-reading-from-file/1810301#1810301) <-- I doubt this will help, but maybe it will.

Also, [this is a great book](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html)... if you are looking to learn more on the subject of iphone networking stuff, check this out.